# why need the `readObject()` overriding method in AtomicReferenceArray?

Tags: java, overriding

As the subject says,why does it need the `readObject()` overriding method in AtomicReferenceArray while there are no `readObject()` overriding methods in AtomicIntegerArray and AtomicLongArray?

Comment: What `readObject` method are you talking about? [There's no such method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReferenceArray.html) in `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceArray`. Can you provide a link and clarify?

Comment: @Sweeper There is such a method (at least in Java 8), it is a private method (as serialization methods can be any access type), so it's not listed in the javadoc.

Comment: It seems the only benefit of that code is that it makes sure that the internal array is of the *exact* type `Object[]`. I don't know why that would be necessary, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason might be explained in the bug ticket  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=788994 (Bug 788994 (CVE-2011-3571, CVE-2012-0507) - CVE-2012-0507 OpenJDK: AtomicReferenceArray insufficient array type check (Concurrency, 7082299)):

> The AtomicReferenceArray class implementation did not properly check if the array is of an expected Object[] type.  A malicious Java application or applet could use this flaw to cause Java Virtual Machine to crash or bypass Java sandbox restrictions.

So they added the `readObject()` method to check the type in the commit https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/e088fb2b1a3413a9d040346fd02ebb6bcd7db9cf (7082299: AtomicReferenceArray should ensure that array is Object[])

Comment: perfect answer! Thanks very much.